# Modify the parent SVG's height that SVG.js creates

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, svg.js

I am using the SVG.js on a WordPress plugin and so far everything is working except for tiny bit. I am loading an external SVG which is loading. Animation is working, but when it bounces to the top, it's getting cut off.

Then I noticed there's another SVG container that gets created one level above and inside that parent SVG is my loaded SVG. I can't seem to edit that parent to have a width and height outside of the default 300px. I read in the FAQ of SVG.js that this is intentional, but I can't seem to find a way to access it to specify a height. Any advice?

```js
var svg_local_load;
var ajax_svg = ajaxsvg.svglocation;


SVG.on(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {

       //gets SVG
       $.ajax({
        url: ajax_svg,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(resp){
         svg_local_load = resp;
        }
       });

       //Loads SVG
       var draw = SVG().addTo('#svg_foo_id');

       var svg_grp = draw.group().id('btn_game_save_id');

       //var parent = draw.parent(SVG.Svg);

       svg_grp.add(svg_local_load);

       svg_grp.animate(1000, 'bounce').move(0, -20).loop(true, true);


      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start by explaining what your code is actually doing.

1. You are starting off an ajax request which **eventually** sets a variable (this is important in a bit).
2. Then you create an `<svg>` by calling `SVG()` and you add it to the element with the id `svg_foo_id`. This element should be a `<div>` or similar (if it its an `<svg>` element you are already wrong here. You didnt post any html code so I need to guess.
3. Next You create a group in the already created SVG.
4. In **THIS** group, you put your loaded content of the ajax request **BUT** this content is not even loaded yet.

At this point I am wondering, why it shows any content at all because `svg_local_load` should still be `undefined` because the ajax request is not done yet and couldnt set the variable.
**Advice:** Put all the code in the `success` callback of the ajax request or call a function from there which creates the svg.

Since you said, that this bit already works, I assume, that the code you posted is not the code you used in your actual program.

Coming back to your question: **You never set the `size()` of the svg you created at the start. You can do that with `draw.size(1000, 1000)`. If there is an `<svg>` a level above that, see point 2**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!


1. Yes - that's correct.


2. Yes it's a div as well. 

3. It's advised in the documentation to group them if I want to do some translation and scaling. I am essentially translating the whole group in this case. The SVG is a completed artwork exported from InDesign.  

4. By having it as async:false, it finishes first. Good idea about the size! I clearly missed the step. I'll try it out .

Comment: To 2. Yes that's an easy way to do that but now you ended up with an outer and inner svg which isn't that nice. You can use SVG(svg code).addTo(...) to create an SVG from your artwork and include it directly. Now you can "move" it around by changing the viewbox (it's not really moving but the result is the same)

Comment: Ahh - that makes more sense now. I didn't consider using viewbox to 'move' it. I find that move() tends to translate it incorrectly but that's probably because the way the SVG gets created. A simple move(0, -20) would move my SVG to a different location.

Comment: You wouldn't use move on the svg itself but instead the viewbox method